# When should PostgreSQL timestamps be created without a time zone?

Tags: postgresql

I have an application where the goal is to have all timestamps in the databes in GMT format should those time stamps be created  without a timezone like so `update_ts timestamp without time zone` or is it safer /better to do so or is it a bad idea to create a timestamp without a timezone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have an application where the goal is to have all timestamps in the databes in GMT format

In this case `timestamp with time zone` (`timestamptz`) is exactly what you want, despite the frankly stupid naming of timestamp types in SQL.

"timestamp with time zone" is actually "timestamp stored in utc and converted on input/output".

"timestamp without time zone" is "timestamp stored and retrieved without time zone conversion".

The types make a lot more sense if you read "with/without time zone" as "with/without time zone *conversion*".

Despite their names, neither type actually stores the time zone. There is no SQL type for what "timestamp with time zone" should actually have been, which is the *local time* stored with an unambiguous indication of the tz offset and time zone the time is in. (A simple UTC offset isn't good enough due to ambiguities around DST transitions).

If you want to do everything in UTC, use `timestamptz` and set the server `TimeZone` to UTC. That way apps that *do* want local time conversion can still get it by setting `TimeZone`.

Comment: Straight to the point and one of the best explanations of what these data types really are. I remember spending a lot of time googling and reading docs to look for timezone storage within timestamptz, only to find there isn't.

Comment: @MarceloZabani Yep. The SQL committee often comes up with ... creative ... ideas, but the timestamp handling has to be right up there with the most special even before you get to the `AT TIME ZONE` pseudo-operator that changes behaviour in subtle ways based on input type, works differently with `TIME` inputs, etc.